# I would like the average/100 to change according to user input in Hindi/100 or English/100

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So Currently the average is calculated in the HTML code. 
If a user input is changed then the average breaks. What could I do to make the average update for every single person,

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)
{
$scope.names = [
    {name:'Priya',age:'19',gender:'Female',English:x[0], Hindi:x[1]},
    ...
    ...
    {name:'Jiah', age:'18', gender:'Female',English:x[18],Hindi:x[19]}
    ];

$scope.sortColumn ="name";

$scope.$watch('names', function(newVal) {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach(newVal, function(x) {
      total += parseInt(x.English) + parseInt(x.Hindi);
    });
    $scope.total = total 
}, true);


$scope.delete = function (name) 
{
    $scope.names.splice( $scope.names.indexOf(name), 1 );
}   
});
```

**HTML**
This is the code where I want the average to change:

```
 <table>    
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>AGE</th>
        <th>GENDER</th>
        <th>ENGLISH/100</th>
        <th>HINDI/100</th>
        <th>AVERAGE/100</th>

    <tr ng-repeat ="x in names | orderBy:sortColumn">
        <td>{{x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{x.age}}</td>
        <td>{{x.gender}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.English"></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="x.Hindi"></td>
        <td ng-bind="avg=(x.English+x.Hindi)/2">{{avg}}</td>
        <td>
            <button><a href="" ng-click="delete(x)" style="text-decoration:none;">Delete</a></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x.English` and `x.Hindi` are being entered as string values, so you need to parse them.

```
<td ng-bind="avg=(parseFloat(x.English)+parseFloat(x.Hindi))/2">{{avg}}</td>
```

We can't use javascript in Angular expressions, so you have to set a reference to the original function.

```
$scope.parseFloat = parseFloat;
```

As a workaround, you can also use multiplication for parsing.

```
<td ng-bind="avg=(x.English*1+x.Hindi*1)/2">{{avg}}</td>
```

Comment: Gives me NaN, is there any other modification you believe needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `parseInt()` function in angular expression, you need to create a method to calculate `avg`.

Call a method from view like:

```
<td>{{avg(x.English, x.Hindi)}}</td>
```

and, in controller define method that returns the average:

```
$scope.avg = function(e, h){
  if(!h) h=0;
  if(!e) e=0;
  return ( parseInt(h)+parseInt(e))/2;

}
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KI4x1fdHQD7fq8voMokb?p=preview)